# Add class to radio button in choice list field, orchard cms

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I am using orchard cms 1.8.1 and installed a module - [Choice List Field - 1.0.0](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.ChoiceList). Every thing is working fine. But how can i add a class to radio button. For example i am having two radio buttons like: Male and Female, i need to add classes like: rdoMale to Male radio button and rdoFemale to Female radio button how can i achieve this.
Note: In Content type, input field has "Editor css class".

[image]

But for choice list field there is no option to add a class.
[image]

Please Advise

Comment: Don't use that module: Orchard supports enumeration fields out of the box. You don't need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make an alternate view of the Editor of the field :
Modules\Orchard.Fields\Views\EditorTemplates\Fields\Enumeration.Edit.cshtml

Copy it with in your theme in the folder EditorTemplates\Fields\Enumeration.Edit.cshtml and change the code to add the css style you want.